# Sequelize Postgres Transaction block a whole table

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have started working with transactions in my app but I noticed a weird behavior when I start transactions the whole table is blocked, and the app stack with queries to the moment when the transaction is committed.

I need to lock only a single row, I have already tried changing isolation levels and locks but I haven't helped.

I use simple unmanaged transactions.

```js
async function testTransaction(){
const t = await sequelize.transaction({
    isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_COMMITTED,
});

await Video.findOne({where:{"id": "LFbAf1vMnmhXof"}, transaction:t, lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE})
}
```

Comment: How can we guess what your code is doing without seeing the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a 10h I have found a reason of this behavior, using a sync cause locking a table.